# What does "Research" do in Tailraider Safaris?

Tags: monster-hunter-world

When selecting a squad to deploy the Tailraider Safari, it displays their skills at the bottom of the window:

[image: An example of a Tailraider squad's skills]

I assumed the hunting/gathering rating reflects how successful the squad will be on nodes of matching color, but there are never any blue nodes. Only red and green. What does the research (blue) skill accomplish?

[image: A screenshot showing no blue target locales]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Research affects your chances of receiving Investigations from the safari. A higher Research means more Investigations.

Comment: Is there anywhere in-game players supposed to find out about this? I don't see it in the tutorial. Is it in one of the game tips?

Comment: I don't remember reading it anywhere in-game.